# Abstract Algebra idempotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

An element $x$ in a ring $R$ is called an idempotent if $x^2 = x$.
Prove that if $R$ has a unity, $e$, any idempotent $x$ (nonzero); $e$ is a zero divisor.

So, since $e$ is a $0$ divisor, so every element $x \in R$ satisfied $xe=x$,since $x$ is idempotent, $ex^2=x$, but since $x$ is nonzero, $ex=0$, so, $e=0..e$ can't be $0$ divisor..complete lost.

Am I in the right track? someone help..

Comment: The unity $e$ can *never* be a zero divisor. But, an idempotent $x$ is a zero divisor if $x\ne e$, since $x^2=x\iff x(x-e)=0$, is that what you're trying to prove?

Comment: @anon Ah, you added that while I was writing the same. I guess that's how the question should be interpreted.

Answer (score 2):

$$
x^2=x\qquad\iff\qquad x^2-x=0\qquad\iff\qquad x(e-x)=0
$$

Comment: oh...I see..the question should be prove x is 0 divisor. "Prove that if R has a unity, e, any idempotent x (nonzero), e is a zero divisor"..I see..haha.. thanks

Comment: @user67584  What you want to prove is: for every nontrivial idempotent $x$ (ie $x\neq 0$ and $x\neq e$), $x$ is a zero divisor.